# How to disable color output of "ng build"?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need to turn off colors in output of the Angular CLI `ng build` command, namely the summary it writes to console when it finishes. Is there some way, ideally an environment variable or command line parameter, to disable it?

Comment: Not until this issue gets closed: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6478

Comment: If anyone arrives here while searching for the opposite, i.e., how to force colors to show, I found out that `FORCE_COLOR=1` works.

Answer (score 5):

I was unable to find `--no-color` option to disable ANSI characters into angular-cli output..

Anyway you could remove progress output with `--no-progress` or try to add ANSI compatibility to your terminal. Example for jenkins: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/jenkins/ansicolor+plugin

there is an open improvement here:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6478 (thanks jonrsharpe)

while waiting for it there is a workaround provided by zstadler

```
ng build --progress=false | %{$_ -replace "\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]",""}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I stripped the binary and then again escape sequences.

```
ng build --no-progress --prod   | sed -r 's/([^[:print:]])|(\[[0-9]+m)//g'
```

Comment: This doesn't work - ng build (at least as of version 8) outputs build errors to stderr, so if your build has errors their ANSI coloring won't be stripped. You need to rebind stderr to stdout like: `ng build --no-progress 2>&1 | sed -r 's/([^[:print:]])|(\[[0-9]+m)//g'`